# Python - KeyError in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

when I import this dataset:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('lyrics.csv', delimiter = '\t', quoting = 2)
```

it prints like so:

```
                                 lyrics,classification
0    I should have known better with a girl like yo...
1    You can shake an apple off an apple tree\nShak...
2    It's been a hard day's night\nAnd I've been wo...
3    Michelle, ma belle\nThese are words that go to...
4    Can't buy me love, love\nCan't buy me love\nI'...
5    I love you\nCause you tell me things I want to...
6    I dig a Pygmy by Charles Hawtrey and the Deaf ...
7    The song a robin sings,\nThrough years of endl...
8    Love me tender, love me sweet,\nNever let me g...
9    Well, it's one for the money,\nTwo for the sho...
10   All the words that I let her know\nStill could...
```

and if I `print (dataset.columns)`, I get:

```
Index([u'lyrics,classification'], dtype='object')
```

but if I try to prints the lyrics, like so:

```
for i in range(0, len(dataset)):
    lyrics=dataset['lyrics'][i]
    print lyrics
```

I get the following error:

```
KeyError: 'lyrics'
```

what am I missing here?

Comment: change the delimiter from '\t' to ','

Comment: What's missing is you need to figure out what your actual delimiter is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you set the delimiter to be a tab (\t), the header isn't be parsed as you think. 'lyrics,classification' is one column name. If you want to keep the delimiter as a tab, then between lyrics and classification there should be a tab rather than a comma.